# Can a web application open a pdf file that exists on the client side

Tags: php, javascript, asp-classic, client

I have an ASP page, in which the user chooses a value (e.g drawingId) from a list box, and according to this value, ASP builds/calculates a file path, e.g. c:\drawings\file1.pdf, in order to show this pdf file to the user. This path refers to the client's computer, where these pdf files are stored. The server queries the database and knows only the association between the drawingId and the path at the client's computer.

How can I open this pdf file?

I've read similar questions, like [How can my web application written in Java open a file on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806443/how-can-my-web-application-written-in-java-open-a-file-on-the-client-side) or [Can javascript access a filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem), but I haven't understood how to proceed.

I would like this to work with all browsers and also implement this functionality in a PHP site.

Comment: Why don't just [generate the PDF on the server](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/components/how-do-i-generate-pdf-files-from-asp.html) and offer a download functionality to the client?

Comment: what? is opening a file where? im confused.

Comment: I can't generate the PDFs on the server. They are drawings created with Autocad and then saved as pdf at the client.

Comment: You can ask the users to select the pdf file from their local machine and upload it instead of asking to select an id.

Comment: I tried opening it with Javascript, window.location.href="c:\drawings\file1.pdf", but it doesn't understand the address. We need to have a url there. And a url would refer to a location at the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use `file:///`
e.g. `file:///c:/filename.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess after user selects option from a list box, you could construct the path and redirect user to that path which should open the pdf file

eg.

```
file:///C:/foldername/filename.pdf
```

Comment: I created an <a> tag, <a href="file:///C:/Drawings/file1.pdf">My pdf</a>, but it dosn't do anything when I click it. But does this link mean that the file is at the client's side or stored at the server?

Answer (score 0):

it not possible to open client side file from server side code as it running at server side, also due to some security reason browser does not allow to browse client location

refer link [Open local folder from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)